# How to stop "System.Windows.Forms.pdb not included" window from opening when pausing debugger?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, winforms

Every single time that I pause the debugger, a window pops up that says "System.Windows.Forms.pdb not included."

> Under "Module Information", it says
> Version: 2.0.50727.9136 (WinRelRS6.050727-9100)
> Original Location: C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Windows.Forms\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Windows.Forms.dll

How can I make it so that this stops being shown? I don't want any new tabs to pop open, since I have to close these each time before I can make any edits to the code.

I have already tried clicking *Change Symbol Settings*, and running with the *Microsoft Symbol Servers* checkbox checked and with it unchecked. Neither setting fixes this issue.

I have also tried switching the setting *Automatically load symbols for* from "Only specified modules" to the "All modules, unless excluded" option. With that option selected, a new tab pops up that just says "Source Not Available."

Comment: You basically discovered that using Debug > Break All is not a very useful way to debug a winforms app.  It will stop in code that does not need debugging and for which you don't have source code.  Instead, set a breakpoint on the code you need to get working.

Comment: The problem is, I don't always want to have to hit a break point in the code. Very often I need to edit the code, and there is no reason to break on a specific line. Setting an arbitrary breakpoint, clicking through the UI to cause the code to hit the break point, and then deleting the breakpoint just adds several unnecessary steps.


Actually, very often causing the program it to reach the part of the code that I wish to fix would completely bork the project that I am running.

Comment: Is there any way to suppress that warning? I really don't *care* that the pdb is missing; my only goal is to be able to modify my own code.

Comment: @BernoulliLizard try to set 'Generate debug info' option to 'none' under 'Advanced Compiler Settings' window (Properties -> Compile ->Advanced Compiler Settings) and see if it works.